# Symbols required by newlib

Tags: c++, c, arm, bare-metal, newlib

Can I find somewhere where all symbols required by (referenced by) `newlib` are listed? For example, I know `newlib` needs `end` or `__init_array_start(end)` symbols, but that comes from know-how, not from an official doc.

I am an embedded software for ARM engineer and using custom linker scripts with arm-none-eabi GCC toolchain by ARM.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dump the imports with `objdump`?

Comment: How to do that only for newlib's imports? I can dump all symbols, but not sure what you meant.

Comment: Are you using  existing, complete custom linker scripts, which should then already contain definitions for __init_array_start and friends, or working on creating such custom linker scripts from scratch? By the way, the following command should give you the default linker script used by your toolchain linker: arm-none-eabi-ld --verbose.

Comment: I am building LD script from scratch. Also, I am interested in learning about newlib by learning what symbols it uses. I am switching form other toolchain so it is valuable information to me.

Comment: Run arm-none-eabi-ld --verbose then.

Comment: Did  running arm-none-eabi-ld --verbose help ?